# git pull origin master returns fatal: invalid refspec

Tags: macos, git, github, terminal, refspec

Here is the problem:

Whenever I do

`$ git pull 'https://github.com/username/reponame.github.io.git'`

followed by the url I get no problems but when I do

`git pull origin master 'https://github.com/username/reponame.github.io.git'`

followed by the url it returns

`fatal: Invalid refspec 'https://github.com/username/reponame.github.io.git'`

What does this mean and how should I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have already established remote-tracking branches (i.e. `git clone` does this automatically) and want to use `git pull` with the intention of grabbing and merging the latest commits for the current branch off the remote repository, I believe that executing the following will suffice:

```
git pull
```

To achieve the same effect with the inclusion of a refspec (unnecessarily long-winded):

```
// Pulls the remote 'master' branch down to the local 'master' branch
git pull origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

You are receiving that error because the provision of a URL is not how the refspec is formatted.

For further details on how the refspec works and its syntax, consult this [chapter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) from the wonderful [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to pull the branch "master" from a repo using its explicit URL, then the command to call would be:

```
git pull https://github.com/username/reponame.github.io.git master
```

Because "origin" is just a name of a so-called "named remote" which is sort of a configured alias for a repository which allows you to not type that repo's URL each time you access it.

The canonical call to `git pull` is:

```
git pull [<repo> [<refspec> ...]]
```

Where parts in `[...]` are optional — see the [manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html).